# Convert Tuple to Array in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

How do I convert a tuple to an array type?

I have

```
('a', 'b')
```

And want to convert to an array type

```
['a', 'b']
```

The primary reason for the conversion is to use the `arrayMap(~)` function to transform the elements. The tuple type doesn't seem to have an equivalent function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
:) select array(untuple(('a', 'b'))) AS out

┌─out───────┐
│ ['a','b'] │
└───────────┘
```

Thanks